# Creating a .desktop (at .local/applications) for Nautilus broke F11/fullscreen

Tags: gnome, nautilus, fullscreen

Synopsis: wanting to add a few items to the left click menu of Nautilus I a copied the /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop over to ~/.local/share/applications and modified it. Nautilus no longer can go fullscreen and also--somehow--vlc is stuck with the video not embedded in the player and also not being able to go fullscreen (with F11 or by ticking the corresponding box in the menu.) Apropos of nothing, the new items I wanted to add to the left click menu don't work either. :)

This is the modified org.gnome.nautilus.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
# Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
Terminal=false
Type=Application
DBusActivatable=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-7z-compressed-tar;application/x-bzip;application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;application/x-compress;application/x-compressed-tar;application/x-cpio;application/x-gzip;application/x-lha;application/x-lzip;application/x-lzip-compressed-tar;application/x-lzma;application/x-lzma-compressed-tar;application/x-tar;application/x-tarz;application/x-xar;application/x-xz;application/x-xz-compressed-tar;application/zip;application/gzip;application/bzip2;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=new-window;documents;downloads;music;pictures;videos;hanselgretel;local;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window

[Desktop Action documents]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/Documents

[Desktop Action downloads]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/Downloads

[Desktop Action music]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/Music

[Desktop Action pictures]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/Pictures

[Desktop Action videos]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/Videos

[Desktop Action hanselgretel]
Name=Hansel&Gretel
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/.HanselGretel

[Desktop Action local]
Name=Local
Exec=nautilus --new-window $HOME/.local
```

As mentioned, it doesn't actually work. If someone had a clue as to why that is, it'd be nice to know, though it is the "F11 no longer works" that is driving me crazy.
Now, as for its behaviour. The first item (New window) that already existed works just fine. The ones I added: they appear when i left click Nautilus but don't actually work when I click them.

[image]

After I added the modified .desktop F11 stopped working on Nautilus and vlc. It was still working on firefox and a few other programs I tried.

Now, I've managed to get it working on vlc by removing the snap and apt installing the deb. So I'm fine there (don't care that it's a little outdated.)
Nautilus on the other hand I've purged and re-installed but nothing changes. I've also obviously deleted the modified .desktop.

Comment: I don't think .desktop files support shell-style variable expansions like `$HOME`, do they?

Comment: You did try removing the .desktop file to see whether F11 work again? Probably not, because that F11 issue *certainly* is not related to your custom .desktop file.

Comment: I did try removing the .desktop, I certainly did. As a matter of fact I specifically state so in the original post, following the "I've also obviously...". Also, in case anyone wonders, I've alt-f2 r'ed and hard rebooted just for good measure.

Comment: @steeldriver Substituting /home/<username>/ for $HOME doesn't work either, but that's not the main problem. It's the F11/fullscreen. (I keep saying F11 because I am used to the shortcut, but I don't want to imply that there is some other way to get it fullscreen. Nothing works.)